# Saving state/context of user input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have two `.vue` components: `Main.vue`, and `Two.vue` with interaction between them.

`Main` is a form which takes user input on < input > objects (about 30-40 of these inputs), allowing them to enter string or int values.

`Main` contains a button to move into `Two`, and `Two` contains a button, which, on-click, should go back to `Main` and **preserve** whatever values the user has input.

***I'd like to know what approach I need to use if I want to preserve these values in the main page.***

All research suggests this is a form of "state saving", and points to using [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/), but I am not sure if this library is appropriate for such a use-case. It seems to be more appropriate for large applications with complex interactions. Which route do I follow? Do I use something like local storage or cookies?

Comment: To me its unclear what the releation is between your components. Are those pages? Parent Child? But either way maybe this helps: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier

Comment: If both pages are referring to common states and can edit/update states from either page, then yes you need to manage your states and any state management library(vuex/redux)  is appropriate for the use-case. Since you are using vue, vuex will help

Comment: @Estradiaz yes, they are pages